# rails scope for follower_id ( has_many through source )

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql

**Heroku Console**

```
u = User.find(1)
u.followers.count
```

> (1.4ms)  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "users" INNER JOIN "relationships" ON "users"."id" = "relationships"."follower_id" WHERE "relationships"."followed_id" = $1  [["followed_id", 1]]

```
=> 1
```

**relationship.rb**

```
class Relationship < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :follower, class_name: "User"
  belongs_to :followed, class_name: "User"
  validates :follower_id, presence: true
  validates :followed_id, presence: true
end
```

**user.rb**

```
has_many :active_relationships, class_name:  "Relationship",
                                foreign_key: "follower_id",
                                dependent:   :destroy
has_many :passive_relationships, class_name:  "Relationship",
                                foreign_key: "followed_id",
                                dependent:   :destroy
has_many :following, through: :active_relationships, source: :followed
has_many :followers, through: :passive_relationships, source: :follower
```

I want to create a scope that will order users by their followers.count

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use following query, it provides you Users in ascending on basis of their followers. You can replace `asc` with `desc` if you want `User` at top with maximum followers.

```
User.joins(:followers).group('users.id').order('count(*) asc')
```

**Update:**

If you want to use Scope in User model.

```
scope :by_followers_count, -> { joins(:followers).group('users.id').order('count(*) asc') }
```

Comment: but how do i create a scope out of this to put in user.rb? my understanding is that is best to avoid putting stuff like this in the controller and that it should go in the model.

Comment: @TimmyVonHeiss I have updated my answer and moved into scope in User model.